# How to make a change in Qualcomm's Vuforia Sample App

Tags: ios, augmented-reality

I have been looking through the threads at the Qualcomm Forums but no luck since I don't know exactly how to look for what I want.

I'm working with the [ImageTargets Sample for iOS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42MvJ1QgPz8) and I want to change the teapot to another image (a text rather) I had.

I already have the render and I got the .h using opengl library but I can't figure out what do I need to change to make this work and since this is the very basic and I haven't been able to make it work I really haven't ventured to try anything else.

Could anyone please help me out?

I would paste code here but it's a whole project so I don't know exactly what to put if needed please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the *EAGLView.mm* file. There you'll have to load the textures (images) and 3d objects (you'll need to import your .h instead of *teapot.h* and modify *setup3dObjects* accordingly).

They are finally rendered by calling the *renderFrameQCAR* function.

Answer (score 4):

If the case is still valid, here's what you have to do:

1. get header file for 3D object
2. get texture image for this object
3. in EAGLView.mm make this changes:

   - import "yourobject3d.h"
   - add your texture to textureFilenames array(this should be at the begining of EAGLView
   - eventually take care about kObjectScale (by deafult it was about 3.0f, for one object I did have to change it even up to 120.0f)
   - in setup3dObjects method assign proper arrays of vertices/normals/texture coords (check in "yourobject3d.h" file for proper arrays and naming) to Object3D *object
   - make this change in renderFrameQCAR

     ```
     //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, obj3D.numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)obj3D.indices);
     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, obj3D.numVertices);
     ```

I believe that is all... if something take a look at Vuforia's forum, i.e. here: https://developer.vuforia.com/node/2047669

NOTE: default teapot.h does (!) have indices, which are not present in banana.h (from comment below) so take care about that too

Comment: sample header file for 3d object you can find in given link or here: http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/

Answer (score 3):

Actually, teapot is not an image. It's a 3D model stored in .h format which includes Vertices, Normals, and Texture coordinates. You should have a good knowledge of OpenGL ES to understand those codes in sample app.

An easier way to change the 3D model to whatever you want is to use a rendering engine which facilitates the drawing and rendering stuffs and you don't need to bother OpenGL APIs. I've done it with `jPCT-AE` for Android platform but for iOS there is a counterpart called `OpenFrameworks` engine. It has some plugins to load 3Ds or MD2 files and since it's written in C++ you can easily integrate it with QCAR.

This is a short video of my result with jPCT and QCAR: 
[Qualcomm Vuforia + jPCT-AE test video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chsHh0pEhzw)